# How to check apartment state of current thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sta, apartment-state

I have a function which requires to be run in STA apartment state. I wan't to check if it is being run as STA, and if not spawn a new thread which runs in STA.

How can I check which apartment state the current thread is being run in?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this or a similar method inside the function:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState
```